# Vertical margins do not overlap

Tags: css, margin

Vertical margins by default do overlap, for instance if I have one div with bottom margin set to 20px, and the next div top margin to 30px the space between the two div`s should be 30px.

Im my case they do not overlap:

```css
#contentwrap {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#pagenavi {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "contentwrap"></div>
<div id = "pagenavi"></div>
```

Comment: And you want them to overlap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because margin collapse only happens vertically. By setting `display: inline-block`, this breaks the rule since the lower element may try to stick with the element above it.

More information can be found at [here](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/rules-of-margin-collapse/).

Could you show a specific problem so we can tackle it together?. Since styling `display: inline-block;` with `width: 100%` doesn't make any sense

```css
#contentwrap {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
#pagenavi {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id = "contentwrap"></div>
<div id = "pagenavi"></div>
```